# How can I create folder dynamically when moving image?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.3, image-uploading

I use laravel 5.3

My code to move image like this :

```
private function savePhoto($photos, $id)
{
    foreach($photos as $key => $photo) {
        $temp = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'temp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $photo['name'];
        $destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'products'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$id.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$photo['name'];
        if( rename( $temp , $destinationPath )){
            echo 'moved!';
        } 
        else {
            echo 'failed';
        }
    }
}
```

When executed there exist error like this :

> rename(C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\storage\temp\NOTFCjMipXwFhBICo1tj6VXP5Qhv92Fg1kmawcUd.jpeg,C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img\products\77\NOTFCjMipXwFhBICo1tj6VXP5Qhv92Fg1kmawcUd.jpeg):
>   The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)

I think the error occurred because the $id folder is dynamically generated. The $id folder depends on the parameter id. If parameter id = 77, it will be formed like this:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img\products\77\NOTFCjMipXwFhBICo1tj6VXP5Qhv92Fg1kmawcUd.jpeg

So the error occurred because folder 77 does not exist yet

How to make folder 77(This is dynamically generated) first before moving the image?

**Update**

Sample array results from $photos like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => vYcHWLXpwhC9WfXd4XCB2emg83WMtWHphyUBq9MV.jpeg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 1STr51oF8cunSsNEJZyS9upI0hNHYMXjLCCSNonz.jpeg
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [mkdir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

```
private function savePhoto($photos, $id)
{
    foreach ($photos as $key => $photo) {
        $temp = storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'temp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $photo['name'];

        $idDir = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $id;
        $destinationPath = $idDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $photo['name'];

        if (!is_dir($idDir)) {
            mkdir($idDir, 0777, TRUE);
        }

        if (rename($temp, $destinationPath)) {
            echo 'moved!';
        } else {
            echo 'failed';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had try it. But it's the same. Can you update your answers completely? So it adjust to my case

Comment: @samuel, Updated my answer

Comment: There exist error like this : `mkdir(): File exists`. If there are 2 images in the temp folder, which moved only 1 image. Should have 2 images moved

Comment: Added `is_dir()` check. This will eliminate the error. Please, try now

Comment: Concerning "2 images" issue: it looks like their names are identical.